# Why is Titan throwing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: docker, titan

## Steps to reproduce

### Setting up the environment using Docker v1.12.5:

In the host machine's shell:

```
$ docker run -d --name=test.cassandra cassandra:2  # cassandra v2.2.8
$ docker build -t test .  # see below for Dockerfile
$ docker run -ti --rm=true -P --link test.cassandra:cassandra test bash
```

Here is the Dockerfile used to build the `test` image:

```
FROM openjdk:alpine
ENV TITAN 'titan-1.0.0-hadoop1'

#
# Install system packages & Titan
#
RUN apk update && apk add bash unzip && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && adduser -S -s /bin/ash -D srg \
    && wget -O /tmp/$TITAN.zip http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/downloads/titan/$TITAN.zip \
    && unzip /tmp/$TITAN.zip -d /opt && ln -s /opt/$TITAN /opt/titan \
    && rm /tmp/*.zip \
    && chown -R srg /opt/$TITAN/

COPY conf/srg.properties /opt/$TITAN/conf/  # see below for file contents
USER srg
```

And lastly, here is the contents of `srg.properties`:

```
storage.backend=cassandra
storage.hostname=cassandra

cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 50
cache.db-cache-time = 10000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.25
```

At this point there should be two containers running:  one with cassandra, and one running our `test` image.  You should have a bash shell running on the latter

### Launching Gremlin and observing the error

In the `test` container's bash shell:

```
$ cd /opt/titan
$ ./bin/gremlin.sh
```

This should bring up the Gremlin shell.  From here:

```
g = TitanFactory.open('conf/srg.properties')
```

**This should produce the following error:**

```
Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager
Display stack trace? [yN] y
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:55)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:473)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:407)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1320)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:62)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$open.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
    at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:119)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:94)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:123)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:82)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:303)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:44)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.ensureKeyspaceExists(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:572)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.<init>(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:291)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.PoolTimeoutException: PoolTimeoutException: [host=cassandra(172.17.0.2):9160, latency=10000(10000), attempts=1]Timed out waiting for connection
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.SimpleHostConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SimpleHostConnectionPool.java:231)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.SimpleHostConnectionPool.borrowConnection(SimpleHostConnectionPool.java:198)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.RoundRobinExecuteWithFailover.borrowConnection(RoundRobinExecuteWithFailover.java:84)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:117)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:352)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl.executeSchemaChangeOperation(ThriftClusterImpl.java:146)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl.internalCreateKeyspace(ThriftClusterImpl.java:321)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl.addKeyspace(ThriftClusterImpl.java:294)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.ensureKeyspaceExists(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:567)
    ... 52 more
```

## Questions

On a high level, my question is simply **"What is going on here and what can I do about it?"**

I have an existing cassandra (dockerized) on top of which I would like to deploy Titan.  Ultimately, I expect to run a Titan container on each machine running Cassandra, configured to connect to the co-located cassandra container.

Suggestions and questions are, as always, appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On a high level, my question is simply "What is going on here and what can I do about it?"

If you look at the "caused by" chain for the exception, the original one says:

```
Caused by: 
    com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.PoolTimeoutException: 
    PoolTimeoutException: [host=cassandra(172.17.0.2):9160, 
                           latency=10000(10000), attempts=1]
    Timed out waiting for connection
```

At the high level ....

What is going on is that your Gremlin instance is not able to connect to the Cassandra service.  The most likely explanation is there is a problem with network routing and/or firewalling, either across the docker boundary or between the host where you are running stuff and the Cassandra host.

What I would do in this situation is to:

- Check the IP and port number that are being used (per the exception) to ensure they are correct.
- Use network diagnostic tools (traceroute, tcptraceroute, ping, etc) to determine if you can make connections to Cassandra, and where the "blockage" seems to be.

What you do next depends on what you find.